# How to build a query based on a number of different URIs

Tags: java, mysql, rest, refactoring, uri

What I currently have done: Since I am using `aws` lambda and `aws` API Gateway, I have learned to capture specific parts of the URI such as the Path and the queryParameters, and I am building different queries to my database based on the path and parameter given.

Example:

```
https://ApiURI/user?id=id_1
```

Path=User

Parameter=id:id_1

I put both pieces of data in a `Map<String, Map<String, String>`object in which the first string is the key (either a path or a parameter) and the inner map holds the actual value. I did it this way because I felt it would scale better, since I do not know beforehand how many paths or parameters are going to come with the URI **(the idea is to be able to filter a given URI/concept/entity with 0 up to N filters, applying 0 or even all at the same time, and some URIs currently can have 8 filters)**, the path also could have several "slashes" such as `/user/profile` or `skill/profile?date=today` but as of right now it is not the case.

Example: `/course` can have the following filters (also called queryParameters since that's the name I saw AWS giving it at times):

1. skill
2. cost
3. online
4. duration
5. level
6. certified
7. language

I lack the experience to see how this can be made with scaling in mind. Currently what I am doing is something like the following example (queries are simplified for the sake of brevity). In the example, I catch whether or not a certain key appears in the map, and if present, I build the appropriate query. **The biggest problem right now to apply several filters at once is that they can require a Join with different tables** (suppose that for the list before, when `?skill` appears I build a query with an inner join with the table `skill`, and when `?cost` or level appears, I have to make a join with another table called `course`, for example) :

```
if(pathParameters.containsValue("profiles")) {
        if(queryParameters == null || queryParameters.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                preparedstatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from profiles");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(queryParameters.containsKey("zone")) {
            try {
                preparedstatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from profiles where id = ? GROUP BY id;");
                preparedstatement.setString(1, queryParameters.get("zone"));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(queryParameters.containsKey("skill")) {
            try {
                preparedstatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT *  from skills where id = ?");
                preparedstatement.setString(1, queryParameters.get("skill"));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(queryParameters.containsKey("experiencia")) {
            try {
            [....]
            }
          }
        }
```

So summing it up, I have a number of branches of logic that I cannot quite know how to simplify since each branch can have a different query associated, that needs to join a certain table. To avoid having `7!` number of possibilities with IF cases, I would need to build the query more dynamically (it's the only idea I have come up with so far). For that, I would need to join two different queries with different logic, and I do not know if that is possible.

Comment: have you looked at spring boot and CRUD repositories? They do a lot of this for you based on method names https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Comment: @codebrane I am sorry but no matter how much I read I do not see a way to do what I want, tbh. The most similar thing would be Special parameter handling but I fail to see how to use that for my case

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet implemented this options, but so far this looks close to what I am looking for, so I post it as an answer in case someone else may use them in the future, but so far it is a partial answer:

[DbExtensions](https://maxtoroq.github.io/DbExtensions/docs/SqlBuilder.html)  although it's for .Net and not java unfortunately.

http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html

Particularly code like this is what I am aiming for:

```
void DynamicSql(int? categoryId, int? supplierId) { 

   var query = SQL
      .SELECT("ID, Name")
      .FROM("Products")
      .WHERE()
      ._If(categoryId.HasValue, "CategoryID = {0}", categoryId)
      ._If(supplierId.HasValue, "SupplierID = {0}", supplierId)
      .ORDER_BY("Name DESC"); 

   Console.WriteLine(query);
}
```